# react-native useRoute hook : Property '.....' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, hook

In my expo app, I'm using useRoute() hook in a functional component from react-navigation. I also use typescript.

The route I want to navigate to have only 1 parameter: i**dentificationUrl**
when I want to navigate to this screen, it gives me the following error :

**Property 'identificationUrl' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)**

```
  const route = useRoute();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [identificationUrl] = useState(route.params?.identificationUrl);
```

How to add the type of this parameter correctly to useRout?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript

Comment: @satya164 no sorry I tried this :

**type ScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Ubble'>;**  

**const [identificationUrl] = useState<ScreenNavigationProp>(
    route.params?.identificationUrl);**  

and here is my RootStackParamList : 


**export type RootStackParamList = {
...
  Ubble: { identificationUrl: string };  
}**  
but same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used **RouteProp** to type my route and it's work

```
type ScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'name of my route'>;
```